# Firebase PagerAdapter Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use Firebase Android with a PagerAdapter, but can't seem to find a way to get the data and the child elements from firebase to my pager adapter. Does anyone have some ideas?

Here is my Firebase Data

```
[ {
  "author" : "Rav",
  "content" : "This",
  "id" : 33,
  "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/",
  "timestamp" : "13892733894"
}, {
  "author" : "Mihail",
  "content" : "blalala",
  "id" : 44,
  "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/",
  "timestamp" : 241414212
}]
```

I am using this PagerAdapter and trying to get the images to it:

```
public class NovAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

private final Utils.LibraryObject[] LIBRARIES = new Utils.LibraryObject[]{
        new Utils.LibraryObject(
                R.drawable.img_one,
                "Лако"),
        new Utils.LibraryObject(
                R.drawable.img_two,
                "Гро"),
        new Utils.LibraryObject(
                R.drawable.img_tree,
                "Ков"),
        new Utils.LibraryObject(
                R.drawable.img_four,
                "Шеф")
};

public NovAdapter(final Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return LIBRARIES.length;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(final Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    View view = null;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_item);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    final Utils.LibraryObject libraryObject = LIBRARIES[position];

    Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(libraryObject.getRes()).into(holder.img);

    holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(position) + " " + libraryObject.getGlavi(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(final View view, final Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position, final Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView img;
}
```

This is the class i am using

```
public static class LibraryObject {

    private String mTitle;
    private int mRes;

    public LibraryObject(final int res, final String title) {
        mRes = res;
        mTitle = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(final String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }

    public int getRes() {
        return mRes;
    }

    public void setRes(final int res) {
        mRes = res;
    }
}
}
```

And this is my Post.class

```
public class Posts {
    private Long id;
    private String author;
    private String image;

public Posts(){

}

public Posts(Long id, String author, String image) {
    this.id = id;
    this.author = author;
    this.image = image;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

Comment: None of your code seems to interact wit the Firebase Database yet. I recommend starting with the Firebase documentation for Android: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Comment: Well you have to make some changes in order to work. I did start and i have no problem with it but the problem is that there is no support for PagerAdapter and i am trying to figure out a way for that, so i though maybe someone did which would be helpful to a lot people. Anyway thanks for trying